# List app in MyGlass as glassware

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I am developing an app for Glass.

The app uses some options that the user should be able to access in the MyGlass app on the phone. Therefore I would like to get my app listed in the MyGlass app under glassware with an options tab.

However I can't figure out if it's possible to get my app to show there, and if possible how this should be accomplished.

The screenshots illustrate what I would like to do.

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxb4T.png) and [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwGqu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **strongly** suggest that as soon as you feel your Glassware is on track to go into MyGlass that you start the review and distribution process.

You can learn more about it at the [distribute](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/index) page of the Glass Developers site, but there are a few key things to know, particularly when it comes to your request for a settings page:

1. Submit as soon as you think you might be ready (or even nearing readiness), but remember that the review process will take some time, and you should think of this as a closed beta period. So after you've [reviewed the checklist](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/checklist) you should submit your Glassware [using this form](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/form).
2. During the review process they will send you feedback about how to make it more "Glass-like". If you've followed the [design principles](https://developers.google.com/glass/design/principles) and [best practices](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/best-practices), this should go fairly smoothly.
3. The *Settings* page you want is one of the things you'll specify in the form. This will be a URL, and the reviewers will test how well this works as well and how it supports other design criteria.
4. Even if you think your Glassware is perfect, make sure you're open minded to suggestions from the reviewers. Part of their job is to help you make your Glassware great.

Answer (score 0):

The way to get your candidate `glassware` to the `MyGlass` store is covered in this section of the official guides:

https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/index

You can also find [the form](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/form) to submit your app there. Make sure you read through and rigorously followed the best practices before submitting the app, the review process seems to be quite thorough.